# Show Jquery UI Autocomplete only when a special key is pressed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a textbox with autocomplete and I want to show the results only when the dot key `.` is pressed.

I tried:

```
 $("#tags").on("keypress", function () {
     var keys = [];
     keys.unshift(e.which);
     if (String.fromCharCode(keys[0]) == ".") {

     } else {
         $("#tags").unbind();
     }
 });
```

However,  `$("#tags").unbind();` removes all the events from the textbox, and if I press the dot key again, the results won't show up.

How can I fix this? [Live jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vXMDR/36/)

Comment: If you just want to unbind the keypress event, $("#tags").unbind("keypress"); (you should actually be using $("#tags").off("keypress"); )

Comment: I dont want to unbind the keypress event, I want to unbind the autocomplete event and rebind it if  .  is pressed.

Comment: Is something like this what your looking for? I made it emulate what Visual Studio does: http://jsfiddle.net/xHy6n/2/

Comment: Yes! Please, post it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that emulates what visual studio does:
http://jsfiddle.net/xHy6n/2/
It stores the location of the last "." and uses anything after it as a filter for the autocomplete.

```
 $(function () {
     var availableTags = [
         "ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
     var lastDot = -1;

     $("#tags").autocomplete({
         minLength: 0,
         source: function (request, response) {
             if (lastDot>=0) {
                 response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                 availableTags, extractLast(request.term.substring(lastDot+1))));          
             }
         },
         focus: function () {
             return false;
         },
         select: function (event, ui) {
             var terms = split(this.value);
             terms.pop();
             terms.push(ui.item.value);
             terms.push("");
             this.value = this.value.substr(0,lastDot+1);
             this.value += terms.join("");
             return false;
         }
     }).on("keypress", function (e) {
         var keys = [];
         keys.unshift(e.which);
         if (String.fromCharCode(keys[0]) == ".") {
             lastDot =  $("#tags").val().length;

         }
     });

     function split(val) {
         return val.split(/,\s*/);
     }

     function extractLast(term) {
         return split(term).pop();
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding/unbinding, you could try something like this (so you can toggle the activation/deactivation of the autocomplete by pressing `.`:

```
$("#tags").on("keypress", function (e) {
     var keys = [];
     keys.unshift(e.which);
     if (String.fromCharCode(keys[0]) == ".") {
         if(autocomplete_flag == 0) {
             autocomplete_flag = 1;
             $(this).autocomplete( "enable" );
         } else {
             autocomplete_flag = 0;
             $(this).autocomplete( "disable" );
         }
     }
 });
```

like this: http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/fEsN5/6/

Comment: Not sure if you understood the question. I want to do something like the autosuggest in visual studio. The autosuggest should only appear when user presses "."

Comment: The "." will be included in the auto complete string, since none of your "available Tags" contain a "." they wont be matched and added to the autocomplete list, so you will need to strip the "." from the string

Comment: Try adding ".ActionScript" twice. It works only the first time.

Answer (score 0):

if text Barcode Start With ('.') .
jQuery

```
    $("#Barcode").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        open: function () { $('.ui-autocomplete').css('z-index', 50); },
        source: function (request, response) {
            var StrBarcode = request.term;
            if (StrBarcode.match('.') == '.') {
                var SRBarcode = request.term.replace('.', '');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/SearchBarcode",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: SRBarcode },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (!data.length) {
                            var result = [{ label: "No Resalt", value: response.term }];
                            response(result);
                        }
                        else {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.ItemBarcode, value: item.ItemBarcode };
                            }))
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            var label = ui.item.label;
            if (label === "No Resalt") {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
```

and I am Using Asp.net mvc Control

```
 public Task<JsonResult> SearchBarcode(string term)
    {
        var SelectName = from N in db.TBLItems
                         where N.ItemActive == true && N.ItemBarcode.Contains(term)
                         select new { N.ItemBarcode};
        return Task.FromResult(Json(SelectName, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet));
    }
```